# Using @typedef to define a specific function type

Tags: javascript, function, typedef, google-closure, jsdoc

I don't know how much of this (if any) is related to Google Closure or if it's all clean jsdoc, but I tried using @typedef to define a specific type of function like this;

```
/**
 * @typedef {function(paramType0, paramType1):returnType} name.space.and.TypeName
 */
```

also tried

```
/**
 * @typedef {function(paramType0, paramType1):returnType} 
 */
name.space.and.TypeName;
```

where param and return types are the reason I want to define this specification of function. My question is this;

Why do validation tell me that the "Method is not of Function type". I know it's an option to use the type 'Function', but as far as I know, that won't allow me to define parameter and return types? Am I wrong on this as well?

I would much appreciate some assistance on this in any case. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are miss using the typedef, how are you using the declared type? (The second form is more correct).

Answer (score 5):

Typical use of a typedef looks like this:

```
/** @typedef {function():string} */
var SomeFunctionType;

/** @param {SomeFunctionType} x This is a function */
function useFunction(x) {
  ...
}
```

The question is lacking some detail and I expect you actually want a @type declaration to type a value, rather than creating a type name:

```
/** @type {function():string} */
var someFunction = getFunctionFromSomewhere();

someFunction();
```

An overview of the jsdoc annotation can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler

Comment: This is not an answer.  It's more a comment.

Comment: It may or may not be.  As I stated in my comment, the question is incomplete.

Comment: I believe it does answer the question, as described the author is misusing @typedef.  Without the exact error or an example use of the type it is impossible to be more specific.

Comment: I agree with - well - everyone basically. I had already ended up using the latter version which is the correct one. The other one was more a test to try out the jsdoc version as well.
In any case; defining a type and using it is correct in the syntax above and everyone should be dancing - just that my linter is not. Seems to be the Google Closure JS Linter (gjslint) that's trying to guide me here, but the clear example provided by @John is exactly how I use it. Compiles and works :)

Comment: @NinjaTool if you want to add some clarify text to the question, I am happy to provide an answer to an remaining misunderstanding.